# Group by in codeiniter return zero in count if there is no row match

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(status) as status_count, status');
    $this->db->where('u_id', $u_id);
    $this->db->where_in('status', ['2', '3']);
    $this->db->group_by('status');
    $q = $this->db->get('retail_lead');

    return $q->result();
```

i want if no row matches for status 2 or status 3 zero will be return for both or for no matched status

Answer (score 0):

In pure T-SQL it will be:

```
WITH STATUSES AS (
  SELECT 2 AS Status
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3),
COUNTS AS (
  SELECT COUNT(1) as status_count, status
  FROM MYTABLE
  GROUP BY status
  WHERE u_id = @u_id
)

SELECT S.Status, ISNULL(C.status_count, 0) AS status_count
FROM STATUSES AS S
LEFT JOIN COUNTS C
  ON S.Status = C.status
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(status) as status_count, status');
$this->db->where('u_id', $u_id);
$this->db->where_in('status', ['2', '3']);
$this->db->group_by('status');
$q = $this->db->get('retail_lead');

if($q->num_rows() > 0){
    return $q->result_array();
} else {
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: It is not what i am asking about

Comment: You can simply return `0` instead of return false